# Activities overview doesn't work!

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, 19.10, activities-overview

I'm using latest Ubuntu (19.10) activities overview in top-left corner doesn't work however "Activities Overview Hot Corner" in tweak is enable!

Comment: You obviously tried already to see if it works after restarted gnome shell or after loging out hten back in?

Comment: @vanadium I did, it doesn't work!

Comment: I temporarily do not have Ubuntu 19.10, so I cannot check myself right now.

Comment: I'm using 20.04 and I have no activities activity that I can figure out how to access.  It's especially frustrating because when I seek answers to trivial issues, many (most?) have answers that address Ubuntu prior to its dropping the Activities paradigm.

Very Frustrating.